# Django `migrate` command fails with: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' "IntegerField"

Tags: python, django, django-models

Can you explain it to me? Why this is my models.py? I get this error message: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
    )
    nomor_hp = models.IntegerField(

    )
```

Comment: Your model looks fine.  Can you post the full trace of the error?

Comment: The problem is not with this code. Show the part where you are using this model, and the full traceback.

Comment: @RedCricket this is my trace of the error: [link](https://pastebin.com/5a0qx0wi)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what happened is this.  You added the `nomor_hp` field to your `Contact` model.  Then you ran `makemigrations` and got output that looked something like:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'num' to foo without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
```

You probably selected 1 (like above) and just hit enter or `''`.  Since `''` is not an integer the `migrate` fails with the message you posted.  The thing to do is:

1) Fix your Contact.nomor_hp field to this `nomor_hp = models.IntegerField(default=None)`

2) Run makemigrations again

3) Edit the offending migrations file (you can find it in the trace output) and in your case it  is the `0003_contact_nomor_hp.py` file.  In that file you should change …

```
   operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='contact',
            name='nomor_hp',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=''),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

… to …

```
   operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='contact',
            name='nomor_hp',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

4) Run `migrate`

Then you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert a string to an integer via `int()` somewhere in your `models.IntegerField` and this is failing because `int()` does not know what to do with a string.

To solve this, ensure your data inputs are all integers or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted the following log in the comments:

```
>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contacts, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contacts.0003_contact_nomor_hp...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\schema.py", line 42, in add_field
    super().add_field(model, field)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 421, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 168, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 239, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 790, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 785, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\Heri Prastio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1807, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The problem is probably that you already have some data in the database, therefore, you are not able to add the column `nomor_hp`.

You have 2 options here:

1. Add a default value to the filed (`IntegerField(default=0)`)
2. Make the field nullable (`IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)`)